# How to configure Apache to handle OPTIONS request without invoking script

Tags: apache-2.2, options

We built a RESTful server with CORS enabled which means it will be getting OPTIONS requests from the clients. We would like to have the webserver handle these, not our downstream REST-server. How can we configure Apache to handle these request without invoking any external scripts?

In NGINX it is something like this:

```
   if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "ACCEPT, ORIGIN, X-REQUESTED-WITH, CONTENT-TYPE, AUTHORIZATION";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200;
   }
```

But we can't find a similar mechanism in Apache. [edit] The trick is not to set the headers, thats obvious in Apache, but to return '200' from the request without invoking any external script. [/edit]

Need it for our local dev-servers which don't run NGINX. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If yes please share it with all of us.

Comment: i can't think of a way to generate a response in apache. But you could rewrite the OPTIONS request to a file to achieve the same result?

Comment: I had to setup this for NGINX, but your question gave me most of the needed info :D ... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For setting those headers in Apache httpd, have a look at the [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html). Here is an example (found after some quick googling) that appears to do what you're looking for: http://saulalbert.net/blog/access-control-allow-origin-xmlhttprequest-day-what-fun/

On a side note, since your setup appears to be using NGINX in higher environments, it would be wise to use to NGINX for local dev servers as well, if possible.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but this is for the servers running on our personal Macbooks, for demo and dev purposes. At the moment we generate the header from the REST-server code, but this is even more undesirable then not running NGINX ;) I know how to set headers for Apache, but I can't find anywhere how to have Apache handle the complete request on its own. Then our REST servers need to be aware of OPTIONS requests at all.

Comment: I looked into the solution you gave, but the part where Apache return without calling any script is missing. The crucial part :) For completeness I would like to mention that for the real requests, you only need the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";' header, not the others. They are only used by the OPTIONS preflight request.

Comment: Ah, I see. My understanding is that this *should* just work. If it doesn't, have a look at your apache confs to see if there are any limits on `OPTIONS`. Have a look at this discussion for some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581106/how-to-configure-apache-to-let-php-handle-options-http-requests